# display scoll bar for more categories in catalog search box in magento

Tags: javascript, catalogsearch

in home page on top, you can see " All categories and there is a dropdown button"

if you hover mouse on the dropdown button, you can see some 50 categories. i want to restrict

that 50 to 10 and to see next 40 , customer have to use scrollbar.

demo example : http://www.amazon.in

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via CSS by adding this to your stylesheets.

```
.catsearch-dropdown ul {
  height: 280px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: auto;
}
```

The height will show 10 lines of text of your drop down. The overflow-y: scroll will give you the vertical scroll bar. The width auto will prevent a horizontal scroll bar, this part is optional.